# ChemFig: Numbering each step in (defined) scheme environment

Tags: chemfig, chemmacros

Before asking my question I have several related issues concerning *chemfig* and *chemmacros* packages.

While defining a new **scheme** environment ([link](http://www.mychemistry.eu/2017/04/define-new-floating-environment/)) for *chemfig*, I keep having Errors if I have *chemacros* also loaded.

- Are they incompatible?
- While *chemmacros* is very fine for equations represented by chemical formulas it cannot draw anything and *chemfig* is suitable doing that. Is there any way to have both of them at the same time? Can *chemfig* do what *chemmacros* does and write chemical formulas too?

I'm really confused!

**- How can I number each reaction in an scheme environment using *chemfig*?**
Example:

[image: Scheme]

***Scheme 1*** 1) Nitration 2) Reduction

MWE:

```
  \documentclass[titlepage, 12pt]{article}

%\documentclass[titlepage, 17pt]{extarticle} for larger font sizes
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={8.5 in,11 in},
 left=1 in,
 top=1 in,
 right=1 in,
 bottom=1 in,
 }

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}


\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\lhead{Pre-Proposal - Ardalan Hayatifar}
%\rhead{Addendum}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% For ACS citation Style
\usepackage{achemso}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% use other useful chemistry tools, too, e.g. the handy \ch command:
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}


\usepackage{chemfig}
%for Scheme float


\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{scheme}{hbp}{los}
\floatname{scheme}{Scheme}


% customize captions, define floating scheme environment:
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}







\begin{reaction}
 A + B -> C + D


\end{reaction}








\begin{scheme}
\schemestart
  \chemfig{C(-[:0]{}|{\color{red}H})(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}
    \+\chemfig{{}|{\color{blue}Cl_2}}
  \arrow{->[\( h\nu \)][]}
  \chemfig{C(-[:0]{}|{\color{blue}Cl})(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}
    \+\chemfig{{\color{red}H}(-[:0]{}|{\color{blue}Cl})}
  \schemestop

  \caption{bla bla}

  \label{sch1}
\end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Please -- as usual here -- show us a short compilable code you have tried so far resulting in your issue.

Comment: Sure, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `chemmacros` package itself defines a `\listofschemes` command that you are trying to overwrite with the `\newcommand`. I'm not sure what your goal is here, but you can either use the `\listofschemes` defined by chemmacros, or just name your newcommand differently.

### option 1

```
\documentclass[titlepage, 12pt]{article}

%\documentclass[titlepage, 17pt]{extarticle} for larger font sizes
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={8.5 in,11 in},
 left=1 in,
 top=1 in,
 right=1 in,
 bottom=1 in,
 }

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{scheme}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{caption}

%\usepackage{float}

%\newfloat{scheme}{hbp}{los}
%\floatname{scheme}{Scheme}
%\newcommand*\listofschemes{\listof{scheme}{List of schemes}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
  \ch{ A + B -> C + D }
\end{equation}

\begin{scheme}
\schemestart
  \chemfig{C(-[:0]{}|{\color{red}H})(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}
    \+\chemfig{{}|{\color{blue}Cl_2}}
  \arrow{->[\( h\nu \)][]}
  \chemfig{C(-[:0]{}|{\color{blue}Cl})(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}
    \+\chemfig{{\color{red}H}(-[:0]{}|{\color{blue}Cl})}
  \schemestop

  \caption{bla bla}

  \label{sch1}
\end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

### option 2 (with reactions)

```
\documentclass[titlepage, 12pt]{article}

%\documentclass[titlepage, 17pt]{extarticle} for larger font sizes
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={8.5 in,11 in},
    left=1 in,
    top=1 in,
    right=1 in,
    bottom=1 in,
}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}  % <--------- load the module
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{scheme}{hbp}{los}
\floatname{scheme}{Scheme}
\newcommand*\mylistofschemes{\listof{scheme}{List of schemes}} % <---- change the name here

\begin{document}
    \mylistofschemes
    \listofreactions  % <--------- list of reactions
    \section*{Abstract}

    \section{Introduction}

    \begin{reaction}  % <--------- reaction environment
    A + B -> C + D
    \end{reaction}

    \begin{scheme}
        \schemestart
        \chemfig{C(-[:0]{}|{\color{red}H})(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}
        \+\chemfig{{}|{\color{blue}Cl_2}}
        \arrow{->[\( h\nu \)][]}
        \chemfig{C(-[:0]{}|{\color{blue}Cl})(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}
        \+\chemfig{{\color{red}H}(-[:0]{}|{\color{blue}Cl})}
        \schemestop

        \caption{bla bla}

        \label{sch1}
    \end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Thanks. I cannot get the "scheme environment" to work if I don't have that command there. My problem now is that I cannot have  "scheme environment" forr chemfig and have a "reaction environment" for chemmacros at the same time. ;-(

Comment: you can't get the environment to work if you don't have which command? your code example doesn't have a reaction environment.. can you update your code to properly reflect what you want?

Comment: Sorry. I went over your answer and Option 2 works perfectly fine now. one last question. " equation environment" will give a "list of equations" how can I have a reaction environment?

Comment: isn't the reaction environment already predefined by the chemmacros package? just `\begin{reaction}...\end{reaction}`? you'll need to load the reactions module in the preamble as well.

Comment: if you mean you want a "list of reactions", you can use `\listofreactions` also defined by the chemmacros package.

Comment: I thought so too but when I add  `\begin{reaction}
 A + B -> C + D
\end{reaction}`  I get "The environment `\reaction' is undefined." error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87089/discussion-between-ardalan-and-troy).