# How to label a chemical reaction with chemfig?

Tags: cross-referencing, chemfig

I am trying to add a label to a chemical reaction so that I can reference it just like equations. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\schemestart
$A$ \arrow(A--B){<=>[$\alpha$][$\beta$]}[0, 0.7] $B$
\schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

How can I add a (1) next to that reaction? I tried using `\label{myreaction}` but it didn't work. I noticed there was another question like this one but the only answer uses the `chemmacros` package, is there really no way to do it with `chemfig`?

Comment: Would that help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464824/chemfig-numbering-each-step-in-defined-scheme-environment

Comment: @Schubladenzieher No, I use `chemfig` to draw my reactions. That answer still uses `chemmacros` to draw the reaction.

Comment: No, it uses `chemfig` to draw the reaction and adds a caption and a list of schemes. Maybe this is an alternative for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `chemmacros` in order to number reaction equations. The package that is used to parse the contents of a `reaction` environment can be selected using the  `formula` option. You can chose between the following packages: `chemformula`(default), `mhchem`, `chemist` and `chemfig`.

A compilable MWE which uses `chemfig` for the reaction equation itself and `chemmacros` to number it results in the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=reactions, formula=chemfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
\schemestart
$A$ \arrow(A--B){<=>[$\alpha$][$\beta$]}[0, 0.7] $B$
\schemestop
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to have multiple schemes in one `reaction` environment and still keep the label?

Comment: Do you want individual numbers for each reaction or one number for all reactions? Do you want to align them, e. g. with respect to the arrow?